# Report Visual Studio Identificador compatibles con CLS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, vb.net, vba

os cuento mi problema:

Tengo una tabla llamada Reg0 con el siguiente formato:

| VarName(varchar(255)) | TimeString(char(26)) | VarValue(float) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Temperatura - T1 | 2022-09-12 14:33:24 | 120 |
| Temperatura - T2 | 2022-09-12 14:33:24 | 80 |
| Temperatura - T3 | 2022-09-12 14:33:24 | 3 |
| Distancia - D1 | 2022-09-12 14:34:24 | 21 |
| Distancia - D2 | 2022-09-12 14:34:24 | 4 |

A traves de un pivot he querido sacar una tabla modificada a partir de esta con lo siguiente:

```
select * into ColReg0
from 
(
  select TimeString, VarName, VarValue
  from Reg0 where VarName <> '$RT_DIS$' and VarName <> '$RT_OFF$'
) src
pivot
(
  sum(VarValue)
  for VarName in ([Temperatura - T1], [Temperatura - T2], [Temperatura - T3], [Distancia - D1], [Distancia - D2]) 
) piv
```

Con esto consigo la siguiente tabla:

| TimeString(char(26)) | Temperatura - T1(float) | Temperatura - T2(float) | Temperatura - T3(float) | Distancia- D1(float) | Distancia - D2(float) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-12 14:33:24 | 120 | 80 | 3 |  |  |
| 2022-09-12 14:34:24 |  |  |  | 21 | 4 |

Esta tabla quiero verla en un tablix del reportviewer de visual studio pero al añadirla como conjunto de datos me aparece lo siguiente:

**Error 8   Un campo del conjunto de datos 'ColReg_INF' tiene el nombre 'Temperatura - T1'. Los nombres de campo deben ser identificadores compatibles con CLS**

Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, el problema era que para el origen de datos de informe los campos de las tablas no pueden tener ni espacios ni caracteres especiales. Entonces después de crear la tabla modificada cambio el nombre de las columnas con sp_rename al formato correcto